# Create element until condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, for-loop, while-loop

I want to create elements inside another element until condition is true.
I have tried this code but it's not working.

```
//  calculate span size and it's parent
var homeHeight = $(".home").height();
var homeWidth = $(".home").width();
var homeSize = (homeHeight + homeWidth) * 2;
var spanHeight = $(".back-animation span").height();
var spanWidth = $(".back-animation span").width();
var spanSize = (spanHeight + spanWidth) * 2;
// create span elements to fill it's parent.
var createSpan = function() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    while (spanSize <= homeSize) {
        $(".animation-hide-overflow").append(span);
        spanSize = spanSize + spanSize;
    }
};
createSpan();
```

Note: It's combined with JQuery and I recieve no errors in console.
Note 2: I tried for loop like the bottom but it's not working either.

```
for (spanSize; spanSize <= homeSize; spanSize = spanSize + spanSize) {
    $(".animation-hide-overflow").append(span);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks for mentioning, I forgot to call createSpan function! now it's working but it create span just once. Any solutions?

**jsfiddle for better demonstration:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pooria_h/vqmgmyj0/1/
(It should keep creating span elements until it fills up parent element.)

Comment: You're just defining the `createSpan` function in the posted code, you're never calling it though.

Comment: Is it possible to create a working demonstration? That might help us visualize your problem.

Comment: Show us your html code

Comment: Try adding at the bottom  `createSpan();`

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help. People in SO love fiddles

Comment: About creating it once, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, you are saving the perimeter of the element and the adding it until is bigger than the perimeter of the _home_, which seems odd but without any other code, can't judge. We need more context or html,css.

Comment: I edited my question. I will create a jsfiddle if it can help. Thanks

Comment: placed jsfiddle link. really thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this section

```
// create span elements to fill it's parent.
var createSpan = function() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    while (spanSize <= homeSize) {
        $(".animation-hide-overflow").append(span);
        spanSize = spanSize + spanSize;
    }
}
```

If you pay more attention you can see I've created **span variable** outside of the loop, So this is what happens: Loop works correctly and it increases **spanSize** variable until it equals to **homeSize** variable which is bigger in the start point but the big problem is there isn't a element creation! **span element** is created before the loop.
So this is the correct way:

```
// create span elements to fill it's parent.
var createSpan = function() {
    while (spanSize <= homeSize) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        $(".animation-hide-overflow").append(span);
        spanSize = spanSize + spanSize;
    }
}
```